# Laravel calculate in blade

Tags: php

i have some problems with calculating some prices that i need on my page.
I have variable `$days`, and price like this

`$price = _amount($change->price, $change->currency, get_display_currency());`.

Now that price is clear for example 13.50, but it's price for 1 day, variable `$days` give's me value that i have to multiply with `$price` and give's me correct price for example 40.5$ (if it's value of $days = 3).
If i want to echo $price i need to write $price['value'] to get 13.50, but that's not problem.
Can anyone tell me how to multiple this price with days?

Comment: This question is really unclear. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Trying to multiple $price with $days. 
$multiple = $price * $days;  can't work!

Comment: So just do $price * $days?

Comment: Give's me error always. I know that. But i have to use for example $price = *$days.. what can't work.

Comment: Then what's the error?

Comment: Unsupported operand types

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this?

```
$price['value'] * $days
```

If its in the blade it would be `{!! $price['value'] * $days !!}` or `{{ $price['value'] * $days }}` (however you've got your blade tags set up)

Comment: Yes i can do that, but the problem is how i echo price.
Like that  @include('extranet.amount', ['data'=> $end_price])

Comment: {{$price['value']}} to echo price, {{ $price['value'] * $days }} to echo total price I guess

Answer (score 0):

Actually i solve it on my own.
This is the code to solve it

```
$price = _amount($change->price * $days, $change->currency, get_display_currency());
```

Simple :)

Comment: Huh? So variable $price is actually $change->price?